# Designing data structure

Tags: json, data-structures, document-database

I'm writing a hobby web application. It currently sends JSON objects to the client, which in turn creates them into blog posts. Currently the JSON object looks like this:

```
{"id1": {"title": "title1", "content": "content1", ...}, "id2": {...}, ...}
```

Sometimes order starts to matter. For example if i want to create a random order of display for the blog posts. Currently i use a separate array `post_ids`, which looks like `["id1", "id2", ...]`, and its values are used as keys for the JSON object above.

Obviously, my object could look as the following:

```
[{"id": "id1", "title": "title1", "content": "content1"}, ...]
```

But then i would lose the ability to index by ID and would need to traverse my data every time.

Sometimes i also have an object and i want to get its ID. I could include ID into the initial object:

```
{"id1": {"id": "id1", "title": "title1", ...}, ...}
```

What is the canonical way to design a data structure, that contains these CouchDB/MongoDB style documents?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a canonical way to design these documents, but I know CouchDB and MongoDB both use the same approach:

{ 
   "_id" : 123,
   "title" : "title1",
   "content" : "content ..."
}

The id of the entity is inside of the document. To return a list of documents, you simply return an array:

{
   "posts" : [ { "_id" : 123, ... }, { "_id" : 124, ... } ]
}

I see CouchDB do this a lot with their views.  You see a result with an array and then the documents in that array, with an ID in each document.  The id never appears outside/next to the document.

Also I've seen lots of lightweight indexes like you mentioned:

{
   "ids" : [ 123, 124, 125, ... ]
}

From my experience that is common as well.